# How to deal with small values when calculating percentage errors

Tags: forecasting, error, percentage

I have a forecast and I would like to calculate the percentage error (for example the mean absolute percentage error). Unfortunately some actual values are around 0 and because of this the percentage error get quite high for these timeslots.

My question is what is a common way of treating something like this? One naive approach would be just to exclude the timeslots for the evaluation that have near 0 values. What other ways exist? Can you share your experience about common ways of dealing with that? I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful if you could share experience

Comment: If you exclude actuals that are near zero, then you imply that your forecast for these values does not matter: whether your forecast was 1 or 1,000 will have no impact at all on your overall percentage error. This is usually not a good idea. I very much recommend [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: Thanks Stephan Kolassa for your answer. Would you recommend me to use the "Relative change and difference"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference instead?

Comment: Hm. There are multiple possibilities on that Wikipedia page. It looks like (I didn't study them in depth) they are basically all variants of the MAPE. Such variants crop up now and then, like the sMAPE, or the MAPE with the forecast (instead of the actual) in the denominator. I would say that they get even less interpretable than the "plain" MAPE, so if you want to use percentage errors for higher interpretability, that is not a step forward. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a good way to make percentage errors work if your data contains zeros.

Comment: I would recommend you think about what functional of the future distribution you want to elicit, then use an appropriate error measure ([see here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017)). For instance, if you want unbiased expectation forecasts, look at the MSE, or the RMSE, or potentially scale it by some factor, like the historical average of the series.

Comment: Thanks Stephan Kolassa for your answer. Basically I am already using RMSE for the training of a Artifical Neural Network. But I also want somehow quantify the error in percentage. But I see that this might not be possible if my data contains 0 entries. What do you exactly mean by "scale it by some factor, like the historical average of the series. "? Shall I scale the error at the end or shall each entry for the error calculation be scaled?

Comment: The problem with looking at different error measures (RMSE and percentage) is that the KPIs may be optimized by very different predictions (see the link in my previous comment). Just something to keep in mind. As to scaling, you could calculate the RMSE for each series, then divide this number by the historical average of the series. This gives you a scaled RMSE that is (within reason) comparable between series.

Comment: Thanks Stephan Kolassa for your answer. What do you mean by "each series". Basically I use 3 time series as inputs to the Artifical Neural Network and it predicts one time series (outcome). I do not have mutiple series as the outcome but just one

Comment: Ah, OK. I was under the conception you wanted a percentage error to compare predictions between series (as percentages are assumed to be "comparable" - mistakenly so, IMO). If you have a single series, you can dispense with the scaling, which aims at making errors comparable... but the question then to me becomes why you are looking for a percentage error in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Stephan Kolassa for your answers and effort. I really appreciate it. So I have a prediction of future energy prices and I would like to know how much the percentage error is that I make when using my Artifical Neural Network for predicting them.